# How to pass constructor values to methods

Tags: java

It says here, build two constructors:
one accepts an event number and number of guests
one is a default constructor that passes "A833" and 0

how do I build these constructors, I have this code right now:

```
public Event(String EventNumber, int NumOfGuests) {
    this.EventNum = EventNumber;
    this.NumOfG = NumOfGuests;
}
public Event(){
    this.EventNum = "A000";
    this.NumOfG = 0;
}


public void setEventNumber(String EventNumber){
    this.EventNum = EventNumber;
}
public void setGuests(int NumOfGuests){
    this.NumOfG = NumOfGuests; 
    this.Price = NumOfGuests * PRICE_PER_G;
}
```

how do I pass the constructor values to the `setEventNumber(String EventNumber)` and `setGuests(int NumOfGuests)`?

Comment: You could do `public Event(){setEventNumber("A000"); setGuests(0);}`. But better make the methods `final` then. Not good to call non-final methods from constructors.

Comment: Hint: read about java naming conventions. Fields and variable names go camelCase, always.

Answer (score 5):

Check out below code:

```
public Event(){
    this("A000", 0);
}

public Event(final String EventNumber, final int NumOfGuests) {
    setEventNumber(EventNumber);
    setGuests(NumOfGuests);
}

public void setEventNumber(final String EventNumber){
    this.EventNum = EventNumber;
}

public void setGuests(final int NumOfGuests){
    this.NumOfG = NumOfGuests; 
    this.Price = NumOfGuests * PRICE_PER_G;
}
```

> > How do I Instantiate two objects one that retains the constructor values and one that accepts user data and displays the details for both objects?

```
obj1 = new Event(); --> This will call default constructor Event()
obj2 = new Event("A001", 2) --> This will call parameterized constructor Event(final String EventNumber, final int NumOfGuests)
```

Comment: Yes default constructor is  public Event() { this("A000", 0); }

Answer (score 3):

> how do I pass the constructor values to the setEventNumber and
>   setGuests methods?

Call the methods from the constructor

```
public Event(String EventNumber, int NumOfGuests) {
    setEventNumber(EventNumber);
    setGuests(NumOfGuests);
}
```

> how do I Instantiate two objects one that retains the constructor
>   values and one that accepts user data

Object that uses default constructor

```
Event event1 = new Event();
```

Object that uses parameterised constructor

```
Event event2 = new Event("123", 5);
```

> displays the details for both objects

For that you can make a method in `Event` class

```
public void displayEventDetails() {
    System.out.println("Event number = " + this.EventNum);
    System.out.println("Number of guests = " + this.NumOfG);
}
```

Now you can call this method on any `Event` class instance to display its details

```
Event event = new Event("123", 5);
event1.displayEventDetails();
```

Comment: Hello, how do I Instantiate two objects one that retains the constructor values and one that accepts user data and displays the details for both objects.